# Does the sum of the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin nx^2}{1+n^3}$ define a continuously differentiable function on $\mathbb R ?$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-convergence

$f(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin nx^2}{1+n^3}$

MY TRY:We know that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin nx^2}{1+n^3} \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^3+1}$.So the function is uniformly convergent.

Now derivative of this function is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2nx\cos (nx^2)}{1+n^3}.$But what can we conclude from this$?$Thank you.

Comment: The answer is yes and one way of proving it is to look at the function obtained by replacing x^2 by x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2nx\cos (nx^2)}{1+n^3}$ is locally uniformly convergent and hence the initial series define a continuously differentiable function on $\mathbb {R}$. **QED**

Comment: Suppose $|x|\le R$,then we can have $|f'_n(x)|\le\frac{2\,n\,R}{1+n^3}\le\frac{2\,R}{n^2}.$ Is it sufficient to show locally uniformly convergent?@Arpit

Comment: @SubratKumarJena: Recall that continuity is a local property.

Comment: I think $\sum f'_n$ convergence uniformly on a compact set and pointwise  on$\mathbb R$.so isn't it sufficient to show our original function is continuously differentiable?@Arpit

Comment: Dear @SubratKumarJena: Recall [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/747129/uniform-convergence-and-differentiation-proof-of-remark-7-17-in-rudins-mathemat) result and apply it locally.You will get that $f$ is $C^1$ locally and hence globally.